# Need to accept only % symbol as an input string

Tags: java, regex

I want to accept only % symbol(optional) as a string variable with a number, as in input as percentage. E.G, 1000% or 100% or maybe 2000% or plain string input as 1000 or 2000.

Can we do it with help of a regular expression? or maybe some other validation.

Please help

Comment: Why not? Did you try anything?

Comment: Are you receiving input via a Swing component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex

```
^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?%?$
```

Should work with decimals

Comment: Awesome! worked... with some minor changes :)
^[0-9]?\\d+(\\,\\d+)?%?$

Answer (score 2):

```
^[0-9]+%?$
```

assuming that at least one digit is required and only positive numbers (or `0`) are allowed.

If you also want to allow decimals (you could have mentioned that in your question), try

```
^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?%?$
```

This allows any positive integer or decimal (but not abbreviated forms like `.1` or `1.`). Exponential notation is of course not supported.

Comment: i tried something like this
[code]if(!manageAccountsPayableDto.getOsuus().matches("^(100(?:,0{1,2})?%?|0*?,\\d{1,2}%?|\\d{1,2}(?:,\\d{1,2})?%?)$")) {
   errors.rejectValue("osuus", "","1065");
  }[/code]

Comment: @Alpesh003 So it didn't work? This is exactly the answer at your problem. +1

Comment: It seems to work perfect with patterns like 1000%, 100 but now problems with decimal values like 101.50 or 199.50%

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the digits and % as an optional character.

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$
```

Comment: It seems to work perfect with patterns like 1000%, 100 but now problems with decimal values like 101.50 or 199.50%

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It sounds like you want to sanitize here as well, so "[0-9]{1,}%" or "[0-9]*.?[0-9]{1,}%" to ensure you match fractional percentages.

Normally I might have said, jfgi but this was too much (fun. EDIT)

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

You could do it with a something besides a regex but that would just be a loop that asserts that each character of input is a decimal digit, period, or percent sign, and that they are in the appropriate order.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment :

> it seems to work perfect with patterns like 1000%, 100 but now
>   problems with decimal values like 101.50 or 199.50%

```
^[-+]?\d*\.?\d+\b%?$
```

**Explanation :**

```
"
^        # Assert position at the beginning of the string
[-+]     # Match a single character present in the list “-+”
   ?        # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
[0-9]    # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   *        # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\.       # Match the character “.” literally
   ?        # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
[0-9]    # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   +        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\b       # Assert position at a word boundary
%        # Match the character “%” literally
   ?        # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\$        # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

As a side note : You should really have been able to account for the optional part from @ Tim's answer. Take a look at the tutorial proposed by the other answers.

Comment: Thanz a lot fot the explanation!